# OSX Key chain installed Windows Server Certificate failing

Tags: ssl-certificate, mac-osx

I'm having a problem with an internal SSL Certificate. so I have a domain that is paid for but used for our internal network resources (intranet). there is a Windows Server 2012 Active Directory server using SSL Certificate signed by the Servers Self Signed Root CA Certificate. and this works perfectly on windows (as per the first image below) if the Root CA is not installed it will give the SSL Warning. When the Root CA is installed it works correctly so I know the certificate is not invalid.
[image: Windows Root CA working]

The problem is with OS X without the Root CA installs it comes up with an SSL Warning but won't let the user go to it anyway. when the Root CA is installed into the System Keychain and set to always trust. it just won't connect at all.
[image: Chrome OSX]

I have tried:

1. Switching browser so I have tied on Firefox, Chome and Safari.
2. Using an Older OSX version all the way back to OS X 10.7 and still
   the same problem

OpenSSL output:

```
CONNECTED(00000005) depth=0  verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:1 depth=0  verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate verify return:1
--- Certificate chain  0 s:    i:/DC=ltd/DC=beaconsoft/CN=eddystone-ca
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
--- Server certificate subject= issuer=/DC=ltd/DC=beaconsoft/CN=eddystone-ca
--- No client certificate CA names sent Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
--- SSL handshake has read 2161 bytes and written 293 bytes
--- New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS supported Compression: NONE Expansion: NONE No ALPN negotiated SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 8D370000FC765F11E029CA4E23ED4AE0804CAA88CAE16435514843DAF1C7E7D3
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: EC6F98CE80E8F82A97D2D554335A41FF71B1E13D0097DC0F2755795085B97B426FE95B8EA81D6BE511C28EB3EECFAA51
    Start Time: 1559054773
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

The actual Certificate data has been trimmed to fit.

Comment: Any errors or records in IIS log files? Also check what protocols are enabled and disabled on the server: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols`

Comment: There are no errors in the IIS Log files. and what am i looking for in that protocols registry?

Comment: No errors are expected. Do you see connection attempts there when connecting from Max OS X? About protocols - forget. If it gave SSL warning until root CA was installed - it is able to communicate. Try running from MacOS terminal: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect overlord.beaconsoft.ltd:443` and add output to the question

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get time little tied up with new Firewalls on-prem at the moment

Comment: @SergeyNudnov added to question for you

Comment: It is important to see the untrimmed output of the command - with certificates and everything

Comment: I'm a little sceptical as to why you need to certificate but here it is please note I will now be destroying that Certificate and signing a new one from our server as soon as this is worked out or 24 hours later https://pastebin.com/dZ17y5xC

Comment: I don't see any other causes of your problem, except of certificate-related. Will look at your posting tonight and let you know

Comment: If I was able to help you, could you please mark my answer as accepted by clicking on `v` under the answer's score. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, cause of your problems is the server's certificate.

There are at least 2 things in it, which should be corrected:

- CRL Distribution Point:

  ```
  [1]CRL Distribution Point
    Distribution Point Name:
      Full Name:
        URL=ldap:///CN=eddystone-ca,CN=eddystone,CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=beaconsoft,DC=ltd?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint (ldap:///CN=eddystone-ca,CN=eddystone,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=beaconsoft,DC=ltd?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint)
  ```
- Authority Info Access:

  ```
  [1]Authority Info Access
    Access Method=Certification Authority Issuer (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2)
      Alternative Name:
        URL=ldap:///CN=eddystone-ca,CN=AIA,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=beaconsoft,DC=ltd?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority (ldap:///CN=eddystone-ca,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=beaconsoft,DC=ltd?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority)
  [2]Authority Info Access
    Access Method=On-line Certificate Status Protocol (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1)
      Alternative Name:
        URL=http://eddystone.beaconsoft.ltd
  ```

Your CRL Distribution Point is not accessible to a non-Domain connected Windows and to all non-Windows clients.

As per modern best practices it is advisable to avoid using LDAP in both `CRL Distribution Point` and `Authority Info Access` records.

You could read more, for example, [there](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/designing-crl-distribution-points-and-authority-information-access-locations.aspx)

Also I'm not sure about empty Subject in your certificate. While you still have SAN name defined `DNS Name=Cape.beaconsoft.ltd`, I would put a proper Subject too.

By the way we are discussing a certificate for `overlord.beaconsoft.ltd`, and you sent one for `Cape.beaconsoft.ltd`. But if they are made by the same CA, using the same template - it doesn't really matter - just correct you CRL and AIA records to have `HTTP` only access points

Comment: Could you find another source for industry standard that does not blatantly lie, "LDAP protocol mainly can be accessed only by Active Directory forest members" I call foul bullshit, LDAP is an Open Source Protocol over network any device on the network can open `LDAP://10.1.0.1/` (server IP) and is still supported quite openly by loads of still in development systems, Network Equipment (Cisco, Zyxel) Software for companies, Snipe-it, hell even Google's G Suit has it supported. while the information in that article is useful I would like a second source to validate his claims after he lied

Comment: As to your point about the certificate i sent you i sent you the output from what you said to do `overlord.beaconsoft.ltd`is the certificate, `Cape.beaconsoft.ltd` is the CA.

Comment: @MartinBarker The only certificate in output was one issued to `Cape.beaconsoft.ltd`. If you could provide one for `overlord.beaconsoft.ltd` in the same text format, I could look at it too. As of your fuming about lies, you know you have SSL setup which you don't know why doesn't work. And you are asking for help. And I'm spending my time trying to help you. If you didn't try my advice - you have no more advices on your question there. Choice is yours

Comment: Your advice is to tare down my entire secure structure and restart building it all. I want to make sure it will actually work before I tare it down. as that author lied i need to verify the information he is putting forward this is a business grade network if i tare down all of our security systems for a day to reset it up the network certificates, SSL Certificates, Device Certificates & Code Signing Certificates, I need to make sure it will work.

Comment: @MartinBarker All troubleshooting should be done in a lower environment - name it development, testing or whatever. Create one or two or more virtual machines, install your domain, CA services, IIS and try connecting from Mac. When it doesn't work - apply fixes. When you resolved a problem - apply the solution in production. You cannot run your system reliably having just production.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3cGefJDM, and that article does not work, CRL Distribution Point that is in that article is not the same as what the server is configured to use as it's windows server 2016 it has HTTP support added to the CRL Distribution Points, and the one (out of 4) you extracted do not match the servers setup

Comment: So that article does not work at all i have verified everything inside it my server has multiple CRL and AIA setting but they are still not going into the certificate i have just generated a new certificate and there is still only the 1 LDAP CRL and 2 AIA's the same as the first certificate